# Removing Para tag using dojo

Tags: javascript, html, regex, dojo

My page content is rendering  with para tag.The data is coming from the external url.I have to strip the p tags after rendering on page using dojo.For example

```
<div class="truncateP">
        <p>The Stackoverflow is awesome</p>
</div>
```

My page is displaying 'p The stackoverflow is awesome /p ' which I have to strip using dojo.
I want to get only The stackoverflow is awesome without para tags.

Answer (score 1):

Tried this one on Regexpal:

- Search string: `\<p\>(.*)\</p>`
- Replace string: `\1`

Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could just search and replace the div element.  Eg:

```
<div class="truncateP">
    <p>The Stackoverflow is awesome</p>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    require([
        "dojo/ready",
        "dojo/query",
        "dojo/dom-attr"
    ], function(ready, $, domAttr){
        ready(function(){ // Wait till the page is rendered
            var div = $(".truncateP");
            if(div.length > 0){ // check that the div is found
                var html = domAttr.get(div[0], "innerHTML");
                html = html.replace(/\<p\>|\<\/p\>/g,"");
                domAttr.set(div[0], "innerHTML", html);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

There are a number of caveats with this:

1. If you are loading from an external url then you must ensure the content is loaded and rendered to the screen before try to alter it.  Using ready() will not suffice.
2. The dom query is searching for class = truncateP.  If you have more than one on the page with that class then only the first one will be parsed.
3. It will remove all paragraph elements in the content.